# perl - extracting arguments from function definitions and putting it as comment above it

Tags: regex, perl

```
  ............
 ########### NEED TO PUT ARGUMENTS HERE AS COMMENT #########
 eErrorT ChainCtrlInitChains(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl,
    char* name,
    int instance,
    void* pOwner,
    )
    {
       ....
    }
     .........
```

i want to extract and put it above function definition as comment. There are many similar function definitions.

```
open(my $FILE1, "< a.c") or die $!;
@arr = <$FILE1>;

foreach(@arr){
    if($_ =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg) {               
      my $arg = $1;
      my @arr = map /(\w+)$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;
      print @temp = map ' *  @param[in/out] '."$_\n", @arr
          unless $_ =~ /;\s*$/;
     }
}
```

It works when I use $str, But then I can't splice the arguments as comment above the function definitions.

```
$str = <$FILE1>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
use File::Copy;
open my $FILE,'<','a.c' or die "open failed: $!\n";
$file_slurp = do { local $/;<$FILE>};
$file_slurp =~ s{ ^ ( \w+ \s+ \w+ \s* \( (.+?) \) )}{&print_args($2,$1)}xmesg;
close($FILE) or die "Couldn't close file: $!\n";
copy "a.c","a.c.bak" or die "Copy failed: $!\n";
open my $NEW_FILE,'>','a.c' or die "Truncating a.c failed: $!\n";
print $NEW_FILE $file_slurp and unlink "a.c.bak";

sub print_args {
    ($args,$proto) = @_;
    @comments = map { ' * @param[in/out] '."$_" } split /\s*(?:^|,)\s*/,$args;
    return join "\n",(@comments,$proto)
}
```

Test the code first by removing the `unlink` so that a backup copy of your source is kept on disk. When your'e confident it does what you want, you can put back the unlink so that it seems that your original file was modified in place.

Comment: can't see any output..what is ($2,$1), the argument in print_args.

Comment: @Ad-vic You have to arrange to truncate the original file and print `$file_slurp` to it. Sorry, I forgot to add that part. `$1` is the whole function prototype and `$2` is the argument list.